# Garbage Collector overhead limit exceeded Caused By Array Creation

Tags: java, arrays, garbage-collection, heap-memory

Hello,

My program spent a lot of Time creating Object in the Heap Memory , so at certain  Time i get this Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I can't Put my Full Application in this discussion So i created A prototype to explain what My program is doing.

The part of my program that deal with Creating Object looks as Follows:

```
**The Calling Program :**

public class Example {


public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5000; j++) {
                if (i==j)
                    continue;
                int weight = new Random().nextInt();
                Edge edge = new Edge(new Vertex(i+""), new Vertex(j+""),weight);
                list.add(edge);
            }
        }
  }
```

}

**The Class Vertex :**

```
public class Vertex {
    private String sequence ;

    public Vertex() {
    }

    public Vertex(String seq) {
        this.sequence = seq;
    }

}
```

**The Class Edge :**

```
public class Edge {

    private Vertex source;
    private Vertex destination;
    private int weight;

    public Edge() {

    }

    public Edge(Vertex source, Vertex destination, int weight) {
        int[][] array = new int[500][500];
        //here i need the array to do some calculation
        anotherClass.someCalculation(array,source,destination);
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.weight = weight;

    }
}
```

So as you can see:

I have 5000 Vertices , i need To create 5000*5000 Edges , each edge has An array of length 500*500.

For this reason the memory allocated in the Heap Memory end at certain time,the problem as i understood from many disctions I read is that there is no guaranty that the Garbage Collector Will free memory.

So what are the solution for this problem ? normally I don't Need The Edge's Array after constructing the Edge;the array is only needed during the construction of The Edges.

**Another question** : How can I minimize the Memory Utilisation in my Program ? I tried To turn the int array to char array but it didn't help.

Many Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of this.array? Store the results of some calculation for further use ?

Comment: the purpose is to fill the array with some calculated values , and finnaly to get one value to be the weight of the Edge.

Comment: @Holger unfortunantly it was only an example that  look perfectly like my real Application ,Your First Remark is True , So  I deleted every needless Object Creation , Your second Remark about int to String it was an error.The Solution I'm trying is to use more Heap Memory , my application took a lot of time So i'm waiting For Result.

Comment: Ok, I’m now assuming that you *really need* the `int` values to be represented as `String`s inside `Vertex` objects. Then, you’re still creating almost 50,000,000 distinct `String` instances (inside two nested loops) for only 5,000 distinct `int` values. The easiest to fix, would be the string representing `i`, as `i` doesn’t change during the inner loop, so creating the string in the outer loop before entering the inner loop would already halve the number of strings. However, the better solution would be to create an array, holding all 5,000 strings, at the beginning and only use these.

Comment: @Holger I'm Very Sorry For The Misunderstood , I put int Or String only for the ease of the exemple , normaly the String sequence In Vertex Class Is a sequence that have 300-500 char character .As I explained The Problem Is The Two For Loop I'm Creating A lot Of Object And The Java Garbage Collector dosen't Free Memory .

Comment: Of course, the garbage collector doesn’t free this memory. You are still referencing these objects from your list of 25,000,000 `Edge` objects referencing 50,000,000 `Vertex` objects. ***You*** are the one claiming to need all these created objects. In this regard, it doesn’t matter that the actual strings have a length of 300-500 chars (besides making the issue even worse). Any `Vertex` object created from only a single `int` value input must end up with the same string as all other `Vertex` objects created for the same `int` value. Strings are immutable, you can share them.

Comment: Based On the Last Solution By John Horman , I deleted The Array as Instance Varibale  , now it's Only In The Method , in My opinion The Array After The Construction Of the Edge Dosen't Exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your program actually creates 2 * 5000 * 5000 vertices, i.e. a pair for each iteration of the inner (j) loop. I think that you need to first create 5k vertices and keep references to them in an array for when you are creating your edges.

I assume that the "array" variable is *only* needed for the calculation. If that is true, then use a local variable instead of a instance variable.  That way you don't keep 5k instances of that array--just one while you complete your calculation--reducing the memory usage.

Redefinition of the Edge class:

```
public class Edge {

private Vertex source;
private Vertex destination;
private int weight;
//private int  [][] array;  // don't keep an instance copy of this array if
                            // if it is not needed beyond the calculation.

public Edge() {

}

public Edge(Vertex source, Vertex destination, int weight) {
    int[][] array = new int[500][500];  // array will gc eligible after 
                                        // constructor completes
    //here i need the array to do some calculation
    anotherClass.someCalculation(array,source,destination);
    this.source = source;
    this.destination = destination;
    this.weight = weight;

}
```

}

Comment: thank you for your idea , it helped a little bit by creating more Edge , unfortunantly at certain time even longer than the previous one it gives a Memory Error.

Comment: A key problem in the original code is that you are creating two new vertices for each edge you create.  I'm pretty certain that you actually want only 5000 vertices, not 2 * 5000 * 5000 = 50,000,000. You should create your 5000 vertices first and keep them in an array.  Then, in the loop within the loop you should reference the array to assign the vertex pairs instead of calling new for the first two parameters (in the Edge constructor call.)  I should have put an example of that as well in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is due to following reason.
Everytime you create an object of Edge class

```
Edge edge = new Edge(new Vertex(i), new Vertex(j),weight);
```

the following constructor is invoked

```
public Edge(Vertex source, Vertex destination, int weight)
```

Therefore, for each object creation of `Edge` class the following 500 X 500 integer array is created

```
int[][] array = new int[500][500];
```

which consumes a lot of memory because you are creating around 5000 X 5000 objects of `Edge` class.

So, if you want to store edge weights , try to make a global integer array for it.

Comment: first thing , for each edge i have an integer array with size betwween 300 up to 500 , the size of array is not fixed , only in the example i set it to 500 .second thing i'm using multithreading and i can't use only one array.

Comment: @zakzak Seriously, what you wrote needs 25 TB of memory. Either get them or rewrite it. If the array is only needed for building the `Edge`, then simply don't put it in. You may use an `EdgeBuilder` containing the array and building an `Edge` without the array. You may use `ThreadLocal` for providing you one array per thread. There are countless possibilities (but go for the builder).

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more , i didn't get your idea.thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know that an array index reference is 4 bytes. So a two-dimensional array defined as 500, 500 is 1MB without any data being stored. You're also creating 5000 x 5000 of them. Just the arrays with no other data will be over 25TB.

A GC overhead limit reached occurs when the GC is spending most of its time garbage collecting with view results. And this would be expected since the all of the arrays being created are reachable from the main thread.

You should create and expand arrays as you need it (think of an ArrayList) or only create the arrays when you need them.

If you ABSOLUTELY need all the edges in memory you will either need to increase the heap or learn to serialize the results and load only what you need for calculations.

Comment: First Step I need to Create All The Possible Edge (in this stage i'm getting the GC Overhead Error ), but after that i need only Some Edge from 5000*5000 Edges in the Memory.I tried To Use The Array Only In the Metod And not As Instance Variable but it didn't help ,